# When Uploading CSV file using Import,only 1 record is imported

Tags: php, mysql, csv

We have thousands of records in our CSV file and I want to upload it at one shot.When I am selecting a CSV file,only 1 record is imported into mysql table.Please check the code and let me know how to resolve it.

```
    <?php
//load the database configuration file
include 'csv_css.css';
include 'dbConfig.php';

if(!empty($_GET['status'])){
switch($_GET['status']){
    case 'succ':
        $statusMsgClass = 'alert-success';
        $statusMsg = 'Members data has been inserted successfully.';
        break;
    case 'err':
        $statusMsgClass = 'alert-danger';
        $statusMsg = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
        break;
    case 'invalid_file':
        $statusMsgClass = 'alert-danger';
        $statusMsg = 'Please upload a valid CSV file.'; 
        break;
    default:
        $statusMsgClass = '';
        $statusMsg = '';
}
}
?>
<div class="container">
<?php if(!empty($statusMsg)){
    echo '<div class="alert '.$statusMsgClass.'">'.$statusMsg.'</div>';
} ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Members list
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#importFrm').slideToggle();">Import Members</a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="importdata.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="importFrm">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="importSubmit" value="IMPORT">
        </form>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>id</th>
               <th>ContactID</th>
            <th>ContactOwner</th>
            <th>LeadSource</th>
            <th>First_name</th>
            <th>Last_name</th>
            <th>AccountName</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>EmailID</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Industry</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Today_date</th>
            <th>LinkedIn</th>
            <th>CallStatus</th>
            <th>Website<th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>OtherStreet</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                //get records from database
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY ContactID DESC");
                if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
                    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['ContactID']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['ContactOwner']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['LeadSource']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['First_name']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Last_name']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['AccountName']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['EmailID'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Industry']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Department']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Phone']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Mobile']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Today_date']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['LinkedIn']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['CallStatus']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Website'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Street']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['OtherStreet']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['City']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['State']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Zip']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Country']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Description']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } }else{ ?>
                <tr><td colspan="24">No member(s) found.....</td></tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

importdata.php

```
    <?php
//load the database configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){

//validate whether uploaded file is a csv file
$csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

        //open uploaded csv file with read only mode
        $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

        //skip first line
        fgetcsv($csvFile);

        //parse data from csv file line by line
        while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
            //check whether member already exists in database with same email
            //insert member data into database
$db->query("INSERT INTO contact (id, ContactID, ContactOwner, LeadSource, First_name, Last_name, AccountName, Title, EmailID, Industry, Department, Phone, Mobile, Today_date, LinkedIn, CallStatus, Website, Street, OtherStreet, City, State, Zip, Country, Description) VALUES ('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."','".$line[3]."','".$line[4]."','".$line[5]."','".$line[6]."','".$line[7]."','".$line[8]."','".$line[9]."','".$line[10]."','".$line[11]."','".$line[12]."','".$line[13]."','".$line[14]."','".$line[15]."','".$line[16]."','".$line[17]."','".$line[18]."','".$line[19]."','".$line[20]."','".$line[21]."','".$line[22]."','".$line[23]."')");
        }

        //close opened csv file
        fclose($csvFile);

        $qstring = '?status=succ';
    }else{
        $qstring = '?status=err';
    }
}else{
    $qstring = '?status=invalid_file';
}
}

//redirect to the listing page
header("Location: usait.php".$qstring);
```

Comment: Where is the code of making csv file?

Comment: @Jasmine, are you getting any errors? (if not on the screen, what about in the PHP log file?)

Comment: Instead of insert query, try to print the $line in while loop and check if all the lines are printed.

Comment: And also provide the maximum line length for fgetscv function like fgetcsv($csvFile, 10000, ",")

Comment: It would also be useful if you could add the first line that isn't inserted, it may be data related (i.e. are all the fields filled, are there any odd quotes)

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly caused when you do not have "Auto Increment" set on the ID column, make sure you have Auto Increment enabled for the ID column on your MySQL table and the script should work as expected.